# Compute ELO ranking in SQL view or query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a league system for 2 player games and I'd like to implement an ELO ranking system - as used in chess.

As it stands, I have a working ELO ranking PHP function which takes a list of players and a list of all games played in chronological order and computes each player's ELO rating. At the moment there are not many players, nor are there many games so this is acceptable. However, I quickly see this becoming unrealistic as each query to the list of players recomputes the ELO ratings...

I'm wondering if there's a way I could compute the ELO rating for players in a SQL view, and have it update only if there are changes to the games table?

I'm also open to any solutions which don't require constantly recomputing ELO ratings.

**EDIT:** The 2 tables in my database which are relevant...

players: `player_id | (meta data...)`
games: `player1_id | player2_id | date | (meta data...)`

Comment: can you post your schema? My first suggestion would be to store the ELO value of each player, and update the values with a trigger when inserting your games table.

Comment: They are quite simple at the moment...

I might eventually add `player1_score` and `player2_score` to the games table but the game I'm currently using it for is strictly win/lose (player1 being the winner)

Comment: I meant to store the current ELO ranking in your `players` table... THEN when inserting into `games` you update the `players` score

Comment: And you would do this purely in SQL?

Comment: that will be my first call... but you can code your elo calculations ins php, and "trigger" them whenever a game is saved (asuming you insert in a php script)